# deja vu: Why am I seeing "the application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)"

Tags: c, windows, dll, visual-studio-2017

Platform: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit [Version 10.0.15063]; Xeon CPU E3-1220 v3, 3101 Mhz, 4 Core(s), no HT; 32 GB ECC memory; Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

I am working on NTPD, the Network Time Protocol Daemon, trying to make it more accurate.

My revised version of NTPD ran from 3/16/17 until yesterday, 8/20/17.  I finally got my readTemps.exe C# program working yesterday; all it does is read the CPU and System temperatures every 10 seconds, and waits for NTPD to ask for them via UDP.  NTPD starts readTemps.

However, there was a problem in that NTPD could not start readTemps as Administrator, which is needed, I believe, for readTemps to interface with WMI.  So I put code in readTemps to detect if it is running as Administrator, and if not restart itself thusly.

In test mode, a driver program can start readTemps, access temperatures for a minute, and stop readTemps, but NTPD can no longer do anything!.

At first it stopped in the very beginning when it was trying to request privileges to set the system time (which is not my code and has worked forever).

Now it cannot even load, failing with the error "(t)he application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)."

Using my backup program I replaced the newly compiled versions of ntpd.exe and ntpd.lib with the versions that had run successfully from 3/16--8/20/17, but still I get the (0xc000007b) error.

I downloaded Dependency Walker (DW) and ran it on the ntpd.exe image that worked for 5 months.  DW found the following errors:

- Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not
  found.
- Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a
  missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
- Error:Modules with different CPU types were found.
- Error: A circular dependency was detected.
- Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
- Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a
  missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

In particular, DW finds that dozens of dll's are missing, e..g.,

- API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L1-1-1.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-REGISTRY-L2-2-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-RTLSUPPORT-L1-2-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-SIDEBYSIDE-L1-1-0.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-STRING-L2-1-0.DLL
- etc., etc., etc

.

I can't find these dll's either using the dir /S command, not on C:, the system disk, and not on K:, where Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition is installed.

Does anyone have any idea what could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Can you read it yourself?

Comment: @Eugene Sh.  Can I read what myself?

Comment: Your question. It is not readable.